# Querying from multiple tables in Android SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, simplecursoradapter

I was wondering if it's possible (it should be) to query multiple tables simultaneously (several at once) in SQLite. Basically I have several tables that have the exact same columns, but the data in them is just organized by the table it's in. I need to be able to use `SELECT` to get data from the tables (I heard `UNION` could help), which matches a condition, then group the data by the table it's in.

In other words, would something like this be possible?

```
SELECT * FROM table1,table2,table3,table4,table5,table6 WHERE day=15 GROUP BY {table}
```

I'd rather not resort to having to query the tables individually as then I would have a bunch of `Cursors` that I'd have to manually go through and that would be difficult when I only have one `SimpleCursorAdapter`? Unless a `SimpleCursorAdapter` can have several `Cursor`s?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** The structure of my tables:

```
Main Table - contains references to subtables in a column "tbls"
             and meta-information about the data stored in the subtables

    Subtable - contains reference to subsubtables in a column "tbls"
               and meta-information about the data stored in the
               subsubtables

        Subsubtable - contains the actual entries
```

Basically these tables just make it easier to organize the hierarchical data structure. I suppose instead of having the subsubtables, I could keep the `actual entries` in the subtable but add a prefix, and have a separate table for the meta-information. It just seems it would be harder to delete/update the structure if I need to remove a level in this data set.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reason for the many tables, instead of storing the data in a single table with perhaps a column added to differentiate the sets?  This multi-table approach seems unusual at first glance.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, if they're the same type of data, but differentiate by table, it seems like you're missing the point of columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to forgo having many subsubtables, and instead adding another column like Tim and Samuel suggested. It will probably be more efficient as well then chaining `SELECT`s with `UNION`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create view based on your tables, the query of your view is union of your tables.

```
create view test as select * from table1 union select * from table2
```

now you can filter data as you want
for more info check `union` & `view`

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp